# How do I access Qt qrc folder directly Qt 5.10.1

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I am developing an application in `qml`.
I have a folder `qrc` folder structure like ,

```
qrc:

Features

 - Media
 - Audio
 - TV

graphics

 - media_assets
 - audio_assets
 - tv_assets
```

Features contains respective `qml` files and graphics contains the graphics.
My issue is, after loading a `qml` file from the features it set as the current directly then, after that when I try to access the graphics folder I need to go back **../.../** and access the folder. It is making problems when folder structure is changed.

How can I access the graphics directly from `qrc` like **graphics/media_assets/** from any `qml` files

In the older versions I could access the graphics directly by using `"file://sample.png"`, in qt 5.10.1 it is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
qrc:///
```

From [url QML Basic Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-url.html) documentation:

> When referring to files stored with the Qt Resource System from within
>   QML, you should use "qrc:///" instead of ":/" as QML requires URL
>   paths. Relative URLs resolved from within that file will use the same
>   protocol.